# Open modal without navigation with bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to launch the modal by loading only the partial content (without the navigation content contained in index.html). Is there any way to load the modal with querystring parameter? I was trying to add ?mp=b to templateUrl but that doesn't work.

Here's my code:

```
$scope.openWin = function (size) {

            //alert('openWin')

            var modalInstance = $modal.open({
              animation:true,
              templateUrl: 'Partials/Dashboard.html?mp=b',
              controller: 'DashboardController',
              size: 'lg'
            });
        }
```

I'm referencing this version:
http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

Thank you

Comment: Can you please provide more information?

Comment: Plnkr is empty and I cannot understand what the site navigation should be.

Comment: Sorry about that.. I'm trying to load the partial content into the modal without the content of index.htm which holds the navigation. Is there any way to inject a querystring? In this sample I've tried appending ?mp=b but this isn't being passed properly to $routeparams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a dependency to pass parameters (if possible in your case).
There is a "resolve" property for that, you could "resolve" anything you want :

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'partials/admin/create-group.html',
                controller: 'CreateGroupCtrl',
                windowClass: 'xx-dialog',
                backdrop: false,
                keyboard: true,
                resolve: {
                    group: function() {
                        return $scope.group;
                    }
                }
            });
```

And then in the destination controller :

```
appFormid.controller('CreateGroupCtrl', ['$scope', 'group', function($scope, group) {
. . .
    });
```